# inserting hyperlink in Formattable cells

Tags: r, formattable

I have been trying formattable and it is pretty good.

```
library(formattable)

formattable(df, list(
  age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  grade = formatter("span", style = x ~ ifelse(x == "A", 
    style(color = "green", font.weight = "bold"), NA)),
  area(col = c(test1_score, test2_score)) ~ normalize_bar("pink", 0.2),
  final_score = formatter("span",
    style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(rank(-x) <= 3, "green", "gray")),
    x ~ sprintf("%.2f (rank: %02d)", x, rank(-x))),
  registered = formatter("span",
    style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x, "green", "red")),
    x ~ icontext(ifelse(x, "ok", "remove"), ifelse(x, "Yes", "No")))
))
```

It is taken from:

http://renkun-ken.github.io/formattable/

Now i want to add one more column which is a hyperlink like:

```
file:///D:/CUST_1.html
```

How can i format it so that it works as a hyperlink?

I then use save_to_html to save it.
I am not using Shiny.

kableExtra based solution would work but formattable is the preference.

Comment: Hi have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I think I got something which solved my purpose, I will check the code and get back.

Comment: I have found a way myself, so no worrys! Thanks for replying :)

Comment: Sorry if I am late, posting the answer below, took some time to find out where it was :)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(kableExtra)

K <- Z %>% 
    mutate(ComparisonPair = cell_spec(row.names(.), "html", link = ComparisonPair, tooltip = paste0("Click for Detailed Report",ComparisonPair)),
           Mismatch=cell_spec(Mismatch, angle = 0, 
                              background = "red", color = "white", align = "center"),
           Match = color_tile("green", "green")(Match),
           Source_Records = color_tile("lightblue","lightblue")(Recordset1),
           Target_Records= color_tile("lightblue","lightblue")(Recordset2),
           changes=color_tile("mistyrose","mistyrose")(Col3),
           additions=color_tile("mistyrose","mistyrose")(Col4),
           removals=color_tile("mistyrose","mistyrose")(Col5)) %>%
    kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
    kable_styling(c("striped","hover","responsive"), full_width = T) %>%
                add_header_above(c("Summary Report" = 8)) %>%
                  footnote(general = "Environment Details:",
             number = c(paste("User:", Sys.info()[[6]]),paste("Environment:", Sys.info()[[1]],Sys.info()[[2]]),paste("Machine Name:", Sys.info()[[4]]),paste("Generated At:",as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))),
                                                symbol= "Anything",
                                                symbol_title = "Powered by ",
                                                title_format = "italic")%>%         
                save_kable(title ="Summary Report", file = "D:/RscriptFolder/table1.html", self_contained = T)
```